# To print contents of linked list in an array using a def

Tags: python, arrays, data-structures, linked-list

This is Python Code to create a linked list from scratch. Inside `def printList(self):` I want to print all the values from linked list in the form of an array. But it shows an error which you can see in the end.

```python
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.head = {'value': value, 'next': None}
        self.tail = self.head
        self.length = 1
      
    def Append(self, value):
        newNode = {'value': value, 'next': None}

        self.tail['next'] = newNode
        self.tail = newNode
        self.length += 1
       
    def prepend(self, value):
        newNode = {'value': value, 'next': None}
        newNode.next: self.head
        self.head = newNode
        self.length += 1
    
        print("Head: ", f"{self.head}")
        print("Tail: ", f"{self.tail}")
        print("Length: ", f"{self.length}")

    def printList(self):
        array = []
        currentNode = self.head
        while currentNode:
            array.append(currentNode.value)
            currentNode = currentNode.next
        print(array)

# I want it to print: [2,5,12]

myLinkedList = LinkedList(5)
myLinkedList.Append(12)
myLinkedList.prepend(2)
myLinkedList.printList()
```

Output Error:

```console
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/asmitagharat/Desktop/projects/python/ds.py", line 213, in <module>
    myLinkedList.printList()
  File "/Users/asmitagharat/Desktop/projects/python/ds.py", line 205, in printList
    array.append(currentNode.value)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'value'. Did you mean: 'values'?
```

Comment: Change `array.append(currentNode.value)` to `array.append(currentNode["value"])`. And also: `currentNode = currentNode.next` to `currentNode = currentNode["next"]` Since your nodes are dicts, you access keys, not attributes

Comment: Thank you!
After making these changes, I get the output as: [2]
But I need it to print: [2,5,12]

Comment: I suggest *not* implementing a method `printList`, and instead implementing a method `__str__` that returns a string. Then you can write `print(myLinkedList)` and `print` will automatically call `myLinkedList.__str__()` to convert `myLinkedList` to a string.

Comment: The logic of `LinkedList.__str__` can be mostly the same as that of your `LinkedList.printList`, just replacing the last line `print(array)` with `return str(array)`.

Comment: Also you probably want to modify `__init__` to `def __init__(self, value=None):` and allow creating of an empty linked list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your currentNode is a dictionary object. We can not access the values of dictionary using the `'.'` operator in Python (Unlike Javascript objects which look similar). Use `currentNode["<key>"]` instead.

Example:

```
def printList(self):
        array = []
        currentNode = self.head
        while currentNode:
            array.append(currentNode['value'])
            currentNode = currentNode['next']
        print(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dictionary `currentNode` containing a key `'value'`, then the value corresponding to that key is ***not*** obtained as `currentNode.value`, but instead as `currentNode['value']`.